# ArcGIS Network Analyst for bulk set of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, route, distribution

This is not a problem raised in the middle of a project but rather asking for an approach to start one. I have this project where I am supposed to analyze and optimize the distribution routes for a company for their outlets which are available as GPS location points (about 8000 locations spread across about 64000 sqkm). I am still looking for a method to complete this. I have been looking into Network Analyst for routes and closest facility and such but they all represent only to be used with a few points, not a large number of points like in this case. I have no idea how to go through with this.

Comment: I regularly use the google directions API to generate routes from "A" to "B". You can script this in python and automate it such that it would process all 8000 locations.  But that's routing not closest facility.  You can of course do all that in ArcMap with network analyst but you need a well built network. If you want to automate the processing consider using model builder, that's what its for.

Comment: Thanks Mate... Appreciate it ❤